# How to suppress update check in ehcache 3?

Tags: ehcache

How to suppress update check in ehcache 3.x?

I can set:

```
updateCheck=”false”
```

in ehcache.xml to suppress update check when using ehcache 2.x.  But the XML schema is changed since 3.x.

No config for update check can be found in the official docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there are no update check in ehcache 3