# Programmatically disabling the Ehcache 3.7 update checker?

Tags: java, caching, configuration, updates, ehcache

Our app used to use a legacy version (2.10) of Ehcache where we used to disable update checks via:

```
System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck", "true");
```

We are now upgrading to the latest version of Ehcache (3.7 at the moment).

How does one programmatically achieve the same result?

I cannot find it in the docs.

Will the above still work or should it be changed to `org.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need. There is no update checked anymore.

Comment: I'm assuming you are working for Terracotta and hence you know from the source, right?  Is it documented in some kind of migration doc?

Comment: I used to work for Terracotta but yes, I know from the source. I don't think it's documented since just not there. This question is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603084/how-to-suppress-update-check-in-ehcache-3